# Enable Calabash-sandbox in Shell Script

Tags: xamarin, calabash, calabash-android, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying to access Calabash-sandbox running shell script. Basically my shell script has

```
#!/bin/sh
calabash-sandbox 
calabash-android ---
```

which basically should run calabash-sandbox and the respective commands. It executes calabash-sandbox and stops there.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the script that `calabash-sandbox` runs, and it seems that it creates a new bash session, complete with all the environment variables that calabash will need. So, this is roughly equivalent to if you ran `bash && echo 'test'` in a script - you wont see the `echo 'test'` part, until you exit that session.

But, there are a multitude of ways to push commands into new shell sessions, and one in particular seems to work well for this case. From a [Bash Reference Manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html)

> Bash includes the ‘<<<’ redirection operator, allowing a string to be
>   used as the standard input to a command.

This means you can do something like this: `calabash-sandbox <<< 'echo test'` and it will open your new special calabash session, execute your command in the string, and exit the session.

```
$ calabash-sandbox <<< 'echo test'
This terminal is now ready to use with Calabash.
To exit, type 'exit'.
test

This terminal is back to normal.
```

if you need something more complicated like I did, you can use EOF to redirect a multi line string to your new session, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
calabash-sandbox <<EOF
    export BUNDLE_ID=com.tabrindle.example
    export DEVICE_TARGET=$(system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -e '/iPad/,/Serial/p' -e '/iPhone/,/Serial/p' | grep "Serial Number:" | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')
    export DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://gobbledygook.local:37265
    export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Brindleware LLC (XX8799XB1X)"
    echo ""
    printenv | grep -E 'BUNDLE_ID|DEVICE_TARGET|CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY|DEVICE_ENDPOINT'
EOF
```

Which, exactly as you would expect, will output something like this:

```
$ ./execute_calabash
This terminal is now ready to use with Calabash.
To exit, type 'exit'.

DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://gobbledygook.local:37265
BUNDLE_ID=com.tabrindle.example
DEVICE_TARGET=34fc6d34c34e23454c234523454580b1e2345b9ef
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: Brindleware LLC (XX8799XB1X)

This terminal is back to normal.
```

This may not be the only, or even best way to do this, but it certainly works.